# ¿Cómo hacer un registro de salida a partir de un registro copy de entrada S9(16)V99 COMP-3?

Tags: cobol

Tengo un archivo VSAM SECUENCIAL que toma estructura de un `COPY`. En él tengo varios registros PIC S9(16)V99 COMP-3. Ahora debo hacer un programa sencillo en COBOL que en un archivo de salida tome estos registros totalmente desplegados y los separe con una coma.

El problema es que, cuando intento poner el registro de salida como S9(16)V99, compila pero en el debug se revienta y es por el signo. He intentado tomarlo sin signo y funciona bien, pero es fundamental poder tomar el signo en este programa.

¿Por qué ocurre eso y cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: No me puedo creer que aún no tuvieramos etiqueta para COBOL...

Comment: Hola Diana. Puedes añadir el codigo y añadir ejemplos de registros?

Comment: He hallado la solucion, la razon por la cual no me permitia hacer debug en registro que de entrada es comp-3 y con signo  pasarlo a un registro de salida con signo y expandido completamente, es porque sobre este campo habian otros dos REDEFINE que hacia que en algunas ocaciones el registro que pasara no tuviera la misma configuracion, ni signo porque podia ser otro tipo de dato como numerico por ejemplo y no contener signo. La solucion fue detectar cada REDEFINE para incluirlo en un IF y asi poder asignar o mover el registro que en realidad fuera acorde a cada REDEFINE.

Comment: @DianaPatriciaAlvarezRamos por favor copia ese comentario a las respuestas. Puede servir de guía para otros usuarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

te sugiero usar la función IS NUMERIC sobre el campo para poder prevenir la situación de los REDEFINES que no cumplen con el formato númerico.

Answer (score 0):

> Respuesta copiada desde [un comentario de la persona autora](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97074/como-hacer-un-registro-de-salida-en-cobol-a-partir-de-un-registo-copy-de-entrada#comment180694_97074) de la pregunta

He hallado la solución. La razón por la cual no me permitía hacer debug en registro que de entrada es comp-3 y con signo pasarlo a un registro de salida con signo y expandido completamente, es porque sobre este campo había otros dos `REDEFINE` que hacían que en algunas ocaciones el registro que pasara no tuviera la misma configuración ni signo porque podía ser otro tipo de dato (como numérico, por ejemplo) y no contener signo.

La solución fue detectar cada `REDEFINE` para incluirlo en un `IF` y así poder asignar o mover el registro que en realidad fuera acorde a cada `REDEFINE`.